# Need help interpreting an error: "read_xml.raw"

Tags: r, xml, rselenium

I am following this tutorial [RSelenium and scraping](https://cimentadaj.github.io/blog/2018-03-22-rselenium-and-scraping-catalan-educational-data/rselenium-and-scraping-catalan-educational-data/) All works fine until I get to testing the **navigate_click()** function. (The *set_names* are different to the tutorial as my source website is different.)

```
navigate_click <- function() {
  webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class name",
                               "google-visualization-table-div-page")

  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  webElem$clickElement()

  remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
    read_xml() %>%
    xml_ns_strip() %>%
    xml_find_all(xpath = '//td') %>%
    xml_text() %>%
    set_names(c("PublicationTitle", "County", "Place_of_Publication", "Library")) %>%
    as.list() %>% as_tibble()
}
```

It returns an error:

Error in read_xml.raw(charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)), "UTF-8", ..., as_html = as_html,  : 
  xmlParseEntityRef: no name [68]

Here is the Traceback ...

```
> navigate_click()
Error in read_xml.raw(charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)), "UTF-8", ..., as_html = as_html,  : 
  xmlParseEntityRef: no name [68] 
11. read_xml.raw(charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)), "UTF-8", ..., as_html = as_html, 
    options = options) 
10. read_xml.character(.) 
9. read_xml(.) 
8. function_list[[i]](value) 
7. freduce(value, `_function_list`) 
6. `_fseq`(`_lhs`) 
5. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env) 
4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env) 
3. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)) 
2. remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_xml() %>% xml_ns_strip() %>% 
    xml_find_all(xpath = "//td") %>% xml_text() %>% set_names(c("PublicationTitle", 
    "County", "Place_of_Publication", "Library")) %>% as.list() %>% 
    as_tibble() 
1. navigate_click()
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of your script?

Comment: I have added the code for the function above.

Comment: We need your source website's URL to help. Are you able to include it?

Comment: https://view-awesome-table.com/-Lz90gtPDhIyGUzmdMrE/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the blog that you are looking at a bit puzzling; it's not clear to me how the `navigate_click` function could work, because it is taking an HTML source and calling `read_xml()` on it. Although some HTML pages might conform to strict XML formatting, most are not well-formed XML. In these cases, `read_xml` will throw an error.

Fortunately, the `xml2` package also has a `read_html` function, which will parse your page without any problems. This will not fix your function however, because when you pick out the `td` elements and get their text content, you get a single character vector to which you then cannot apply `set_names`.

In any case, the `rvest` package makes it much easier to read tables from parsed html.

Assuming you have already done `install.packages("rvest")` and created `remDr` as per your example, the following should work:

```r
remDr$navigate("https://view-awesome-table.com/-Lz90gtPDhIyGUzmdMrE/view")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class name", "google-visualization-table-div-page")
Sys.sleep(0.5)
webElem$clickElement()

remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>%
  read_html(x) %>% 
  xml_find_all(xpath = "//*[@class = 'google-visualization-table-table']") %>%
  rvest::html_table() %>%
  `[[`(1) %>%
  `[`(c(1, 2, 3, 7)) %>%
  as_tibble()

#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>    PublicationTitle              County    Place_of_Publicati~ Library               
#>    <chr>                         <chr>     <chr>               <chr>                 
#>  1 ALFRETON AND DISTRICT ADVERT~ Derbyshi~ "Alfreton and Ripl~ British Library       
#>  2 ALFRETON AND DISTRICT ADVERT~ Derbyshi~ "Alfreton and Ripl~ Derbyshire: County Ha~
#>  3 ALFRETON AND DISTRICT COMING~ Derbyshi~ "Alfreton"          British Library       
#>  4 ALFRETON AND DISTRICT COMING~ Derbyshi~ "Alfreton"          Derbyshire: County Ha~
#>  5 ALFRETON AND DISTRICT ECHO    Derbyshi~ "Alfreton"          British Library       
#>  6 ALFRETON AND DISTRICT ECHO    Derbyshi~ "Alfreton"          Derbyshire: County Ha~
#>  7 ALFRETON AND RIPLEY ECHO      Derbyshi~ "Chesterfield"      British Library       
#>  8 ALFRETON AND RIPLEY ECHO      Derbyshi~ "Chesterfield"      Derbyshire: Alfreton  
#>  9 ALFRETON ARGUS                Derbyshi~ "Alfreton"          British Library       
#> 10 ALFRETON ARGUS                Derbyshi~ "Alfreton"          Derbyshire: County Ha~
#> 11 ALFRETON JOURNAL              Derbyshi~ ""                  British Library       
#> 12 ALFRETON JOURNAL              Derbyshi~ ""                  Derbyshire: Alfreton  
#> 13 ALFRETON JOURNAL              Derbyshi~ ""                  Derbyshire: County Ha~
#> 14 ALFRETON JOURNAL              Derbyshi~ ""                  Derbyshire: Magic Att~
#> 15 ALFRETON TRADER               Derbyshi~ ""                  British Library
```